# Java caching objects in several maps vs one list

Tags: java, caching, hashmap

I am currently caching DB objects in list `List<CachedObject>`. CachedObject looks like this:

```
class CachedObject
{
    private int id;
    private int id_type;
    private int id_other_type;

    // getters and setters
}
```

That I am currently getting objects from cache in this functions

```
    public CachedObject getCachedObjectById( Integer id )
    {
        for ( CachedObject cachedObject : cachedObjectList )
            if( id.equals(cachedObject.getId() ) )
                return cachedObject;

        return null;
    }

    public List<CachedObject> getCachedObjectByIdType( Integer idType )
    {
        List<CachedObject> cachedObjectList = new ArrayList<CachedObject>();

        for ( CachedObject cachedObject : this.cachedObjectList )
            if( idType.equals(cachedObject.getIdType() ) )
                cachedObjectList.add(cachedObject);

        return cachedObjectList;
    }
```

Since this is done a lot, would it be faster, when loading cache to distribute information in separate maps (3 in this case):

```
Map<Integer, CachedObject> cachedObject_to_id
Map<Integer, List<CachedObject>> cachedObjectList_to_idType
Map<Integer, List<CachedObject>> cachedObjectList_to_idOtherType
```

and when getting object, just fetch from maps.

**EDIT**:

Number of cached objects in any different time is 20 - 500.

Comment: Why don't you try it ? Bear in mind (and we can't answer this for you) that maintaining multiple maps will increase the population time, but possibly decrease the lookup/retrieval time. Does that matter to you ?

Comment: What is your question here? Give us a specific problem and we may help you. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The number of cached objects is so small that it doesn't matter one bit which one you use. Use the one that you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: Well can you tell me exectly what is the price of keeping that amount of info on a server, loaded in cache... I am a begginer, and my concer is i realy don't know enough about caching, and ots implication on server performace

Comment: Usually Caches follow key, value data structure since the complexity of key value is O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a hash table is usually faster then using a sequential scan method. But if it is only a few values to check (below 10), then it does not matter.

Remark: The method getCachedObjectByIdType returns a mutable list. If the client code is not under you control, you might convert it to an immutable list.

I slightly tend to use maps in you case. Reasons:

- The access will be faster
- The access time keeps constant and does not vary when more data comes in
- No object allocations are needed for the access. You need one for the iterator and one for the array list. Maybe another for converting it to an immutable list.

But the code gets more complex. When you have to scan through 500 objects in the worst case, this means, you code can be two orders of magnitude faster, by using hash maps. However, this may have no effect on the application. Questions to ask:

- What is the access frequency to these objects? Is it something very central which is accessed very often?
- Do I really want to do an extra test with 500 elements, to check that the over all performance is acceptable?
- How often do I need to update the cache and rebuild the data structures?
- Build the maps completely or use lazy loading?
- Who do I solve concurrency issues? Is there concurrent modifications of the maps, or is it read only?